# SAPUI5: Compiling Declarative HTML is not working

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I saw this code sinppet in the SAP documantion:

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/91/f1454b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm

I tried to use it in this simple example below.

what I get is this error message in the console:

***Uncaught TypeError: sap.ui.core.plugin.DeclarativeSupport.compile is not a function***

how do I solve it?

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>  
<title>Declarative Programming for SAPUI5 - sample01</title>
    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
    type='text/javascript'
    src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
    data-sap-ui-modules='sap.ui.core.plugin.DeclarativeSupport'
    >
    </script>

<script>
function addButton(){
    console.log('addButton');
 $("body").append('<div id="button"><div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.Button" data-text="This button is added dynamically"></div></div>');
 sap.ui.core.plugin.DeclarativeSupport.compile(document.getElementById("button"));
}
setTimeout(addButton,10);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UI5 doesn't work with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469120/ui5-doesnt-work-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Should work this way:

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>  
<title>Declarative Programming for SAPUI5 - sample01</title>
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
          src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
          data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
          data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
          data-sap-ui-modules="sap.ui.core.plugin.DeclarativeSupport">
  </script>
<script>
  sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
    $("body").append('<div id="button"><div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.Button" data-text="This button is added dynamically"></div></div>');
    sap.ui.core.DeclarativeSupport.compile(document.getElementById("button"));
  });
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Live example: https://jsbin.com/gegubuzuni/1/edit?html,output